# Response type depending on statuses

Tags: typescript

I need to help to create a TypeScript type for my `fetch` response which can have properties depending on the response status.

The following is where I wanted to use the types,

```js
const api = (url: string) => {
   return fetch(url)
}

const login = () => {
  const res = await api("...");
  console.log(res.data.roles);
}

const createDoc = () => {
  const res = await api("...");
  console.log(res.data.documentId);
}
```

When the response is failed with status code not equals to zero, the response has `status` and `message`:

```js
// status not equals to 0 == failed
{
  status: 20, 
  message: "Failed"
}
```

When the response is succeeded, the response will contains `status`, `message` and different data depending on the operation. For example the success login response,

```js
{
  status: 0, 
  message: "Login success",
  data: {
    roles: ["operator"]
  }
}
```

and the success document creation,

```js
{
  status: 0, 
  message: "Document created",
  data: {
    documentId: "887394"
  }
}
```

and this is what I have tried,

```js
type ApiResponse =
  | {
      status: number;
      message: string;
    }
  | {
      status: 0;
      message: string;
      data: { roles: string[] };
    }
  | {
      status: 0;
      message: string;
      data: { documentId: string };
    };

const api = async (url: string): Promise<ApiResponse> => {
  const res = await fetch(url);
  const json = await res.json();
  return { status: json.status, message: json.message };
};

const login = async (): Promise<void> => {
  const res = await api("...");
  // Property data does not exist on type 'ApiResponse'
  console.log("%s", res.data.roles[0]);
};

const createDoc = async (): Promise<void> => {
  const res = await api("...");
  // Property data does not exist on type 'ApiResponse'
  console.log("%s", res.data.documentId);
};
```

there are TypeScript errors when accessing `res.data` in `login()` and `createDoc()`.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you considered using a HTTP status instead of adding this to your body? It's a best practice.

Comment: Those are the external endpoints. I'm trying to create types to be used in my application.

Comment: Makes sense, so what have you tried so far? You made the structure of the 3 responses pretty clear. I assume you're able to write a type for each of those.  Then your return type can be `Response1 | Response2 | Response3`. I assume you tried this. (if not, try it!). Where do you get stuck with this?

Comment: My bad, and I have updated my code.

Comment: You need to do something to convince the compiler that the response is the appropriate success, possibly by checking existence of properties, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w6QDeW).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, that is working.
I was too naive that the type will be determined depending on the status in runtime.

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) `res` from `ApiResponse` to the relevant [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) member.

You *could* try to do this by inspecting the `status` property, but for failures it could be any `number` whatsoever, *including `0`*, according to your type definition.  TypeScript lacks *negated types* (as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#4196](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4196)), so there's no way to express `number & not 0`.  To work around this you could build a [custom type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) called `isFailure()` or `isSuccess()` which checks `status`, but even after you do that you'll find that you still need to check *which* success you have.  In your example, `await api("...")` gives no indication to the compiler which data will come back in case of success.  You might be able to encode that by providing something more specific than `"..."` that the compiler could inspect, but that's not how the question was asked, and it's not necessarily feasible anyway.

So, instead, I'd probably use [`in` operator narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) to check for the existence of the properties you need to access.  For example:

```
const login = async (): Promise<void> => {
    const res = await api("...");
    if (("data" in res) && ("roles" in res.data)) {
        console.log("%s", res.data.roles[0]);
    }
};

const createDoc = async (): Promise<void> => {
    const res = await api("...");
    if (("data" in res) && ("documentId" in res.data)) {
        console.log("%s", res.data.documentId);
    }
};
```

This works because the `"data" in res` check identifies a success, and `"roles" in res.data` or `"documentId" in res.data` identifies the specific response type you're looking for.  The compiler knows that if `res.data` exists and `res.data.roles` exists, that `res.data.roles[0]` is a `string` because only the third union member of `ApiResponse` matches that shape, and it has a `string[]` as `data.roles`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAgmCWAlCBnMB7Adi6BeAUFEVAD5QDehx1KwAhsAK4oBcUmjAtgEYQBOAbirUinVCjoBzCG1p94mSUOoBfYaQrqa9JqygAGZSNHipMqHIVKtxACYM6bclD7oANqlnB5igNoBdKBUjIjVqMkpjIloGZjZDGxMUCWkvH2soqHt6Jyz0AGMuCExgAElbNKsgkOr8fHysWig6BChcZpQQTHyoAApGPjdKxQBKNgAFV054HAAeOCRUDGwIAD429cjiBuxgF1Q25oB3Ong9gDMIYHyAC37BkZqdpoArFCxDuhOz-ZQAOjeWF6j3UfCuA0wFAsOjiUEBmD+MV0ABooGJkmY2PC-uiUtBgvgCXV6o09m50JIFJ9Ot0+mMoJN0NM5gA3dDwWzrXCbdTPPZglCfb57FrwXoAIj+UvFIOo8HOfQl2To4qgVIFIygADItX1xa4PChVerUH9lSNNVtjM93BA-uTJBKAKRG1ECs0OP4G1C+fT+WXENREvlQfJghgQAAiBWpXR6wImUxmEFmbI5XJ51BDAqFpxFCAlUr+Mpq8sV4uVxshGu1uqVBSKJXKVd+HvoFs0mRtHntFOdrtbyrNDbETdsAdChIEQA)